# How to calculate basic components like trend, momentum, correlation and volatility in Pandas(Python)

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies

I am new to quant. finance and trying to calculate  `trend`, `momentum`, `correlation` and `volatility`. Below are the functions I have created

```
def roll_correlation(first_df, second_df, rolling_period):
    """
    Rolling correlation
    """
    return first_df.rolling(rolling_period).corr(second_df)


def roll_volatility(df, rolling_period):
    """
    Rolling volatility
    """
    return df.pct_change().rolling(rolling_period).std(ddof=0)


# ASK: is rolling momentum calculation is correct
def roll_momentum(df, rolling_period):
    """
    Rolling momentum
    """
    return df.pct_change(rolling_period)


def roll_returns(df, rolling_period):
    """
    Rolling returns
    """
    return df.rolling(rolling_period).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, -1]].pct_change()[-1])


def trend(df, rolling_period):
    """
    Identify trend
    """
    return df.apply(lambda x: x.autocorr(rolling_period))
```

Apart from `volatility` calculation I am not sure about others are they look ok? Is there any external or builtin `pandas` library to calculate these basic components?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't really about a single topic. If it is about converting an algorithm to Python, use StackOverflow, if it is about the formula for a specific technical indicator these are mostly covered in duplicate questions. The indicators referenced are also quite basic and easily researched online.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define rolling momentum. If you define it as the percentage change between the end and the begin of a period, your code is correct.

Comment: thanks, what is the other way, mean of the percentage change ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick follow-up if you want to calculate the *rolling momentum* as *the mean of the percentage change*, you can modify the roll_momentum function accordingly. You may try,

```
def roll_momentum_mean(df, rolling_period):
    return df.pct_change().rolling(rolling_period).mean()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/45640)